# Is it possible to adjust the opacity in the R cartography package?

Tags: r, gis, opacity, cartography

Hi–I'm trying to set the opacity of a layer to 0.6. Is this possible in the R cartography package? For example in var1 and var2 of this propTrianglesLayer:

```
mtq <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/mtq.gpkg", package="cartography"))
# Employed Active Population 
mtq$OCC <- mtq$ACT-mtq$CHOM
plot(st_geometry(mtq), col = "lightblue4",border = "lightblue3",
    bg = "lightblue1")
propTrianglesLayer(x = mtq, var1 = "OCC", var2 = "CHOM", 
                  col1="green4",col2="red4",k = 0.1)
layoutLayer(title = "Active Population in Martinique, 2015")
```

Comment: usually you can do this by taking a color's hex code and adding the alpha as two extra values

Comment: e.g. `green4` is `#008B00` (check `paste(sprintf('%02X', col2rgb("green4")), collapse = '')`), you might try `#008B007F` for 50% opacity or `#008B00BF` for 75% (in general, use `sprintf('%02X', round(255 * pct))` to get `100*pct`% opacity)